# Optimal vehicle routing on map

Tags: algorithms, optimization, routing

Currently I am developing a piece of software that solves the vehicle routing problem.

The task is the following:

- I have several vehicles along the town
- I have lots of destination points along the town
- Vehicles have delievering product on board, and the product is uniform (it doesn't matter if you receive it from vehicle A versus vehicle B)
- Let assume that vehicles can not run out of products
- The number of destination points is greater than the number of available vehicles
- I need to calculate optimal routes through multiple points for every vehicle to minimize the average transportation time

My naive approach is the following:

- find nearest points for each vehicle using k-means clustering with the raw euclidean distance between map points (LngLat points)
- for each vehicle for each destination point from the set of vehicle's nearest destination points calculate optimal routes using other destination points as intermediate points and find routes with smallest avarage transportation time (optimal route from point A to point B crossing several intermediate points can be received from Google Maps API so it is not necessary to use TSP algorithm for it).

It seems that this approach may give results which are not optimal.

Is there better approach which provides better accuracy and/or smaller amount of API requests?

Comment: What has to be transported from where to where?

Comment: @Raphael Let assume that vehicles have all delievering products on board. They need just to pass through the destination points.

Comment: @zavg So in this analogy, they're delivering something like coal (where it doesn't matter if you receive coal from truck A versus truck B), rather than something like parcels (where there's no point in truck A driving past my house if my parcel's on truck B)? And we have the simplifying assumption that trucks can carry arbitrary amounts of coal so we're not worried about them running out? And your goal is to minimize the total distance travelled by your fixed fleet of trucks.

Comment: Note that the one-vehicle version of the problem is essentially metric TSP which means that it's hard but *a lot* of work has been done on heuristics and approximations.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, the product is uniform like coal and let assume that the vehicles can not run out of it. I need to minimize an average waiting time across destination points. Also I am using real world data from Google Maps api where traffic conditions are changing in the real time (i.e. graph weights are functions of time), but we can also omit this additional condition.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Also Google API can give me optimal route from point A to point B crossing several intermidiate points. This is the feature I am using in my naive solution.

Comment: @zavg How do you know that the route found by Google is optimal? Note that if you are essentially asking "how do I improve my implementation?", you are offtopic for [cs.SE]. "How do I improve my algorithm?" is ontopic, and helpful pointers have already been given.

Comment: @Raphael I suppose that they use Dijkstra's algorithm with optimizations (for example, according the information from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430142/what-algorithms-compute-directions-from-point-a-to-point-b-on-a-map)

Comment: @Raphael Speaking in theoretical way we can just assume that I already have an efficient algorithm which can find optimal route from point A to point B crossing several intermidiate points. The question is if there are certain ways to improve the whole algorithm? I don't not where it is better to ask this question since Stackoverflow covers primarily coding problems, not algorithmical.

Comment: I'm happy that this is an algorithms question, rather than implementation, not least because the Google Maps API is something of a red herring. GMaps doesn't re-order destinations: e.g., if you ask for a route Los Angeles-Boston-San Francisco-New York, it gives you exactly that and doesn't say "Hey, why not do LA-SFO-Boston-NY instead?". So, you're asking how to solve an **NP**-hard problem with access to an oracle for a problem in **P**, which is just as hard as solving it without the oracle. Also, how do you define optimal? Traffic conditions might change while you're running the algorithm.

Comment: @DavidRicherby There is optimizeWaypoints option in GMaps API v3. If it is set to true, the DirectionService will attempt to re-order the supplied intermediate waypoints to minimize overall cost of the route. So the result will contain the re-ordered permutation of the input waypoints. For example, if the input was:
  Origin: Los Angeles
  Waypoints: Dallas, Bangor, Phoenix
  Destination: New York
then the optimized output will be ordered as follows:
  Origin: Los Angeles
  Waypoints: Phoenix, Dallas, Bangor
  Destination: New York.

Comment: And how does that work out for many intermediate points? Chances are, they are either slow or suboptimal (cf @DavidRicherby's comment). Regarding: "The question is if there are certain ways to improve the whole algorithm?" -- do you mean your "naive approach"? Then trivially, yes (every algorithm can be improved). What exactly do you have in mind? What goals should be attained? A question like this is too broad and open-ended at the same time.

Comment: @Raphael I did not test Google's API algorithms on large numbers of intermediate points (since basic API access license allows just up to 23 intermediate points). For a few amount of points it shows satisfying latency.

Comment: @zavg Which leads us back to: what is your question? If your current approach is fast enough for you, and you effectively use a black-box, what help do you expect?

Comment: @Raphael My main question is about improvements which can be made to my naive approach I had described in question. The main goal is to increase accuracy. Currently I have only tested Google API requests but not the whole algorithm, because I decided to discuss my algorithm here in order to find out if any more effective approaches exist.

Comment: Achieving an optimal solution is out of question, given that we are talking about an NP-complete problem. My gut feeling is that your current heuristic could be good enough in practice and any notable improvement in prediction quality might introduce notable costs in runtime. So I'd suggest you implement it and see what you get.